# CSV Python: Adding values to empty column without deleting the other

Tags: python, csv, edit

I want to add some data to an existing column in .csv file. To do that, I'm using csv.DictWriter() to access specific column, but for some unknown reason (at least for me :D) it deletes old values and then adds new.
My question is, what's the problem?? Here's part of my code, where is problem most-likely located.

```
    month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")
    day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")

    with open('{}_{}.csv'.format(month, day), 'w', encoding = 'utf-8', newline = '') as file:
        labels = ['city']   #creating labels for rows
        for hour in range(24 + 1):
            labels.append(str(hour))
 
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = labels, extrasaction = 'ignore', delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()   #displaying labels for rows

        for line in zip(city, temperature):
            writer.writerow({'city': line[0][0].text, '{}'.format(hour): line[1].text})
            #line[0][0].text, line[1].text are regular strings
```

city and temperature are arrays, each containing some HTML code achieved from some websites (using library BeautifulSoup) which has to be converted into regular string (.text).

Comment: It may only be possible to write an entire row/column, in which case you could capture the existing contents of the row, modify it to include your new values and then write it?

Comment: You can just open the csv file with `pd.read_csv(filename)` as a pd.DataFrame object, add the column with `df['new_column`] = my_list and then save it with `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`